# How to apply columnDefs on jquery Datatable with saveState opiton to true

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables-1.10

I have the following very simple example using `jQuery Datatables v1.10`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

 <script
          src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"
          integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ="
          crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.16/datatables.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').DataTable(
            {
            "columnDefs": [
                { "orderable": false, "targets": 1 },
                { "orderable": false, "targets": 2 }
            ]
        });
    });
</script>  
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.16/datatables.min.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2011/04/25</td>
            <td>$320,800</td>
        </tr>
 </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
 </table>

</body>

</html>
```

Simple and works just fine. Remove the `Sorting` options from the columns just as I want to. However I want to use the `stateSave` option:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').DataTable(
            { stateSave: true},
            {
            "columnDefs": [
                { "orderable": false, "targets": 1 },
                { "orderable": false, "targets": 2 }
            ]
        });
    });
```

But now the sorting is again available for all columns (the configuration from `columnDefs` is not applied).

So what I want to achieve is using the `stateSave` but still have the configuration for the sorting applied.

I am playing with

```
"stateLoadParams": function (settings, data) {
                //console.log(settings);
                settings.aoColumns[1].orderable = false;
                console.log(settings);
            }
```

Like so:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').DataTable(
            { stateSave: true,
            "stateLoadParams": function (settings, data) {
                //console.log(settings);
                settings.aoColumns[1].orderable = false;
                console.log(settings);
            }},
            {
            "columnDefs": [
                { "orderable": false, "targets": 1 },
                { "orderable": false, "targets": 2 }
            ]
        });
    });
```

But I am still not able to reapply the sorting options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole config should only be one object. You are creating multiple objects and therefore multiple arguments for the main `datatable()` function. Only the first argument is used for setting the internal options and the others are being ignored

Try

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').DataTable({
    stateSave: true, 
    columnDefs : [
          { "orderable": false, "targets": 1 },
          { "orderable": false, "targets": 2 }
    ]
  });
});
```

Comment: You are absolutely correct. Combining it into one object gives me exactly the result I want. Thanks.